# Working with Contacts

Tags: swift, cocoa, contacts

Relatively new to Contacts and have hit a wall working with urlAddresses: and emailAddresses: and hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

What works so far:

I'm able to read my address book and extract the organizationName, contact phone numbers, etc. into my variables for use.  However, I can't seem to decipher the urlAddresses: and emailAddresses: and the Apple API reference sends me in loops.

Here's basically what was working for me.  assume that myContact is a contact record successfully extracted from the AddressBook using the Contacts API.  The following all work:

```
someStringVariable = myContact.organizationName
someStringVariable = myContact.postalAddress[0].value.street
someStringVariable = myContact.phoneNumbers[0].value.value(forKey: "digits") as! String
```

Now, attempting to apply the same logic to urlAddresses: and emailAddresses: causes my program to crash.  I know I'm missing something, but can't quite figure out what I'm missing.  I've tried:

```
someStringVariable = myContact.urlAddresses[0].value as String
```

and on a whim, I tried things like:

```
someStringVariable = myContact.urlAddresses[0].value.url as String
someStringVariable = myContact.urlAddresses[0].value.value(forKey: "URL") as! String
```

My first thought was that the value property was stored as an NSString, but the API reference lists urlAddresses: as CNLabeledValue, and a bit more digging revealed that the Label is an NSString, but the Value property is stored as a "value type".

Following through the links in Apple's API Reference to try and find what the value type was, I started with CNContact, which led me to urlAddresses: and then on to CNLabledValue.  That led me to the Value: Value Type, and clicking on that brings me back to CNContact... so I'm caught in an infinite loop :)

Can anyone offer me a straight forward explanation of how I can extract the URL as a string?  I thought maybe I could do it with a value(forKey:) but I can't seem to find what the Keys would be if they exist, and I'm not quite sure how to print out the contents of urlAddresses: without causing a crash.

I'm having the exact same problem with emailAddresses: so I'm assuming I'm making the same mistake on both.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: What is the actual error or crash you're seeing?

Comment: You should be able to access `myContact.urlAddresses.first?.value` which should already be typed as `NSString`. Are you sure the crash isn't because `urlAddresses` is empty? Accessing [0] would cause a crash in that case

Comment: Yep.. That's exactly what was happening... because I wasn't fetching the urlAddress or emailAddress keys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. So I found the solution and it was a complete noob problem.

I wasn't loading the keys for urlAddresses or emailAddresses so they didn't exist.

Doh!

Added those keys as follows and my code now works correctly.

```
let keysToFetch = [
                CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
                CNContactPostalAddressesKey,
                CNContactEmailAddressesKey,
                CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
                CNContactUrlAddressesKey] as [Any]
```

Basically, I was chasing my tail looking in the wrong place!